# Is it possibel to change Laravels behavior in overriding .env files?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables, environment

The 5.3 docu [says](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#environment-configuration):

> You may also creating a .env.testing file. This file will override values from the .env

I misunderstood this, i was thinking:

if i have 20 entries in `.env`, 
i am able to change only one of them, if i create a new file (e.g. `.env.new`)
and add the only changed key here. but laravel does not really takes all keys from `.env` and overrides them with all keys of `.env.new` - **laravel does not** use the `.env`, it ignores it completly and takes only the file `.env.new`.
So after all, in my example here, i only have 1 key in my `$_ENV` instead of 20.

Is this really the wanted behavior?
If yes: Can i change it in the way, i was thinking it *should* work?

Comment: Is it that big of a deal to make a separate .env file for phpunit? It's only like 20 lines. Yes it is wanted behavior to have isolated environment files -- it's part of the point of different environments.

Comment: 1) phpunit is not related here in my question 2) we are not talking about deals

Comment: The `.env.testing` file is for PHPUnit. If you are going to quote the documentation, you should at least read the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: dear @JeremyHarris instead of treating other people and their reading, you should do this for yourself. the docu says `when running PHPUnit tests or executing Artisan commands` and this "or" is important for me and there is no need to quote anything more, my question covers everything that is necessary to answer my question. so keep your advises for yourself. thanks.